# How to prevent display: grid from auto-stretching children table rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a main (container) div called "passives_div".
I have 3 tables inside this div.
If one of the tables has fewer rows than any of it's sibling tables, those table rows *stretch*, and I need to know of a way to stop stretching.

Here is a screenshot of what's happening.  The screenshot shows the 3 things.. the resulting display, the affected HTML, and the CSS used.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `align-items: start` on `.passivesDiv`.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with fixed hight of row of table